# turborepo packages built before app not found on vercel

Tags: vercel, turborepo

I have the following folder structure for my turborepo monorepo:

```
apps/
    shop
    admin
packages/
    types 
    ui
```

The different packages apps are name respectively inside of `package.json`:

- shop
- admin
- @my-app/types
- @my-app/ui

My root directory in Vercel is set to: `apps/shop`

I am trying to build the "shop" app with "types" and "ui" being it's dependencies on Vercel with the following command:

`cd ../.. && turbo run build --scope=@my-app/types && turbo run build --scope=@my-app/ui && turbo run build --scope=shop`

First when I try to deploy, it says that it cannot see modules from `@my-app/types`, however, if I re-run deployment and tick "Build with existing cache", the app deploys fine.

Comment: Can you please post your `turbo.json`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're running those build commands one after the other? If you define your build pipleline in `turbo.json`, all you need to do would be `pnpm -w exec turbo run build --filter=shop`. The w flag tells pnpm to run this from the monorepo root so you don't need to `cd ../..`. Then, assuming your pipeline(s) are set up properly, turbo should take of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to the turborepo and not sure if this helps, I just found a similar answer to your question on Github:

https://github.com/vercel/turbo/discussions/1347

It's related to this:

https://turbo.build/repo/docs/core-concepts/monorepos/task-dependencies

Also, @ambiguous58's answer looks good to test, so you may need to try to combine them.

---

I followed the documentation, and found this:

```json
// scripts in the root package.json file
"build": "turbo run build",
"build:apps": "turbo run build --filter=...{./apps/*}",
"build:packages": "turbo run build --filter=...{./packages/**}",
"build:config": "turbo run build --filter=...{./config/**}",
```

```json
// turbo.json
{
  "$schema": "https://turborepo.org/schema.json",
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"], // this is where the magic happens
      // these folders are cached
      "outputs": [
        "dist/**",
        ".next/**",
        "!.next/cache/**"
      ]
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

It is smart enough to build the necessary packages in order. You need to add the `build` command to each project in order to let Turbo work. It depends on every build command.